# Python turtle shapes

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am drawing something with python turtle , i used the shape functions but the shapes overdraw the others before them (i can see the shapes moving) , and i get just the last shape:

```
`up()
goto(-200,-200)
down()
shape("circle")
shapesize(2,1,1)
fillcolor("black")
up()
goto(-300,-100)
down()
shape("circle")
shapesize(4,4,1)
fillcolor("black")
up()
goto(-100,-100)
down()
shape("circle")
shapesize(4,4,1)
fillcolor("black")`
```

I am looking forward for your answers , thank you !

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want those shapes to stay in place (i was trying to draw a skull (the eyes and nose)) while i could use turtle.circle for the eyes the nose i was trying to draw has an elliptic form

Comment: I have the same problem, moving shapes as default behavior is suprising form me, but ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`turtle.shape` changes the shape of the turtle as it's drawing. To actually draw that shape where it is, you need [`turtle.stamp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.stamp):

```
up()
goto(-200,-200)
down()
shape("circle")
shapesize(2,1,1)
fillcolor("black")
stamp()
up()
goto(-300,-100)
down()
shape("circle")
shapesize(4,4,1)
fillcolor("black")
stamp()
up()
goto(-100,-100)
down()
shape("circle")
shapesize(4,4,1)
fillcolor("black")
stamp()
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `turtle.stamp()` function